# How to compare String and how to get selected String value to other methods?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here i am using two EditTexts for getting some number as integer value ..

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />
```

Now Im planning to do some calculation 
some

```
   int i1,i2,i3;
    String t1,t2,t3;
    EditText et1,et2,et3;
    int result,comp;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
       et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    //and also storing to string like
                       t1=et1.getText().toString();
                   t2=et2.getText().toString();
                       t3=et3.getText().toString();
               i1=Integer.parseInt(t1);
               i2=Integer.parseInt(t2);
                   i3=Integer.parseInt(t3);
                       comp=i2-i1;
}
```

/*here int some x=10; my problem is how to check conditions i need to get comp value if its selected (by entering on two EditTexts) else One editText(i3 valsu)
any one help me ....*/

```
       public int CalculateUsage(int customersUsage)
                {
        int x=10;
        comp= customersUsage;
        if(comp!=0)
        {
        customersUsage=comp;
        result=(customersUsage*x) ;
        }

        else if(i3 !=null)
        {
        customersUsage=i3;
        result=(customersUsage*x) ;
        }
}
```

Comment: There are a number of issues with this code that would cause it to not compile: no semicolon after `int x = 10`, the variable `comp` does not seem to be declared, and finally, you're trying to compare `i3` (a primitive, `int`) to null. What is the actual logic that you're trying to build here?

Comment: Also, there is no compelling reason to "declare all of the variables on top" -- this just makes your code very hard to read. You should declare and set variables at the point where you use them. For example: `EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);` will make your code *much* more readable (for yourself and others.)

Comment: okey...i did my changes just now tell me how to get integer values comp,i3 to my conditions

Comment: can u pls say wat d problem u facing on it?

Comment: im getting error like  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.welcomeui/com.android.welcomeui.WelcomeUIActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer.parseInt() throws an Exception if the String representation isn't actually an integer. You should make a try-catch block and should set the values to 0 respectively, or the desired default value

```
try{
    i1=Integer.parseInt(t1);
} catch(Exception e) {
    i1=0;
}
etc...
```

Because the edit text value is currently "[empty]".

EDIT:
The edit text are currently empty because you haven't yet set anything to them.
The ems="10" that you have in you layout isn't the edit text value.

Comment: yes its working thanks dude..but i need to reset i1,i2 when i select i3 else i3 reset while i1 &i2 selected. what to do ?

Comment: when you mean selected? typed a value? enter a button? in what "event"?

Comment: ha after every action completed i need to reset all text..i tried but it getting null value

Comment: I don't get your question. But one way or the other this is basic android development, get a View from layout and change it's properties. Numerous step by step tutorials over the web.